# Menu button effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to make a menu like one I have seen but cant work out how it's done.  The one I have seen is on a wordpress site but I don't work with wordpress.

This is the menu I want it's the top menu and as you can see it slides as you hover. 
http://www.netenterprises.co.nz/

I don't want to do this with flash and want to know if anyone can help or point at any info that might help me get there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lava lamp menu http://www.google.com/search?q=lava+OR+lavalamp+menu

This is cool! http://play.swpdsgn.net/magmalamp.html CSS lavalamp

Comment: your the man that what i was looking for but god knows i could not find it lol

Comment: You are welcome - as a reward, please write I with upper case I and remember that it's = _it is_, whereas its = _something that belongs to it_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is what you need like [steel-blue menu](http://apycom.com/menus/4-steel-blue.html) you can change the color like you want or you can also choose another style of menu there

Answer (score 0):

or using only css: http://jsfiddle.net/seler/KAu6t/

Comment: not the same thing sorry

Comment: Like this http://play.swpdsgn.net/magmalamp.html

Comment: @1ftw1 i do not understand. it's exactly the same thing.